# How do these cloud forms grow?

Tags: clouds, wind

What conditions would cause these windswept clouds at sunset in Michigan?

Do these cloud forms have a name?

[image: Sunset Michigan]

Answer (score 10):

Looks like Cirrus Fibratus (Ci fib) to me.

See e.g. [Wolkenatlas](http://www.wolkenatlas.de/wolken/wo10219.htm) or [Clouds Online](http://www.clouds-online.com/cloud_atlas/cirrus/images/cirrus_fibratus_10.htm).

Regarding the formation of Ci fib, [Name of Clouds](http://namesofclouds.com/cirrus/cirrus-fibratus.html) says:

> Cirrus fibratus clouds are formed when winds at high altitudes are strong and flow over the cold air from below. The combination of the warm air and the moisture is usually unevenly distributed hence the trail of fine fibers at the ends of such clouds.